# Group_by does not aggregate based on selected column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset called country_num that looks like this

```
Country     num
Other       5
Other       6
Other       16
USA         30
UK          25
China       12
```

I tried to use group_by to combine the three "Other" rows like this

```
country_num %>%
   group_by(Country) %>%
   count(num)
```

But the three "Other" rows did not aggregate. Why is that and what can I do about it?

Comment: What is your expected output? Are you trying to `sum` the `num` values? `country_num %>% group_by(Country) %>% summarise(num = sum(num))`

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

This answer is basically what @Ronak Shah said in his comment above.

--

Is this what you want?

```
library(tidyverse)
country_num <- read.table(
  text = "Country     num
          Other       5
          Other       6
          Other       16
          USA         30
          UK          25
          China       12",
  header = TRUE
)

country_num %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  summarise(num = sum(num), n = n())

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Country   num     n
#  <chr>   <int> <int>
#1 China      12     1
#2 Other      27     3
#3 UK         25     1
#4 USA        30     1
```